# Value of type 'String' cannot be converted to 'String()'. VB.Net

Tags: arrays, vb.net, string

```
Dim StateNmList() As String, StateName As Object
    StateNmList = ("Alabama", "Alaska", "Arizona", "California", "Colorado", "Connecticut", "Delaware", "District of Columbia", "Florida", "Georgia","Hawaii", "Idaho", "Illinios", "Indiana", "Iowa", "Kansas", "Kentucky", "Louisiana", "Maine", "Maryland", "Massachusetts", "Michigan", "Minnesota", "Mississippi","Missouri", "Montana", "Nebraska", "Nevada", "New Hampshire", "New Jersey", "New Mexico", "New York", "North Carolina", "North Dakota", "Ohio", "Oklahoma","Oregon", "Pennsylvania", "Rhode Island", "South Carolina", "South Dakota", "Tennessee", "Texas", "Utah", "Vermont", "Virginia", "Washington", "West Virginia","Wisconsin", "Wyoming")
    StateName = Split(StateNmList, ",")
    Return StateName
```

Returns the errors: 
BC30311 Value of type 'String' cannot be converted to 'String()'.
BC30311 Value of type 'String()' cannot be converted to 'String'.

I'm not sure what Im doing wrong.

Comment: The first error corresponds to the line beginning StateNmList =  and the second on the next line beginning StateName = .

Comment: It looks like you are trying to pull a name from a list. `Dim StateNmList As String()` to declare an array, `StateNmList = {"Alabama"...} to populate an array with a literal; then `StateName = StateNmList(n)` to fetch one; and it should be `StateName As String` which isnt actually needed at all.

Answer (score 0):

Split is used to separate a single string into an array of strings, something like this (untested):

```
dim StateNameString as string
dim StateNameArray() as string

StateNameString = "Oklahoma, Arkansas, Hawaii, ..."
StateNameArray = StateNameString.Split(",")

for each stateName as string in stateNameArray
  msgbox (stateName)
next stateName
```